# Subgroup membership problem for Noetherian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, computability-theory, geometric-group-theory, decidability

I am interested in the status of the subgroup membership problem (MP) for finitely presented Noetherian groups. That is, given a finite presentation $\langle X,R\rangle$ for a Noetherian group,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Input:} & u,v_1,\ldots,v_n \text{ words in } X^{\pm}\\ 
\text{Decide:}& u \in \langle v_1,\ldots,v_n \rangle
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Of course, relevant to this is the possibility that every finitely presented Noetherian group is virtually polycyclic (and so has solvable MP). Is this still an open <s>conjecture</s> question? Any information on decision problems for Noetherian groups will be also greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it's a conjecture (the claim that every f.p. noetherian group is virtually polycyclic); it's an open question. You conjecture something when you strongly believe it's true.

Comment: @Ycor agreed! So, is it still open?

Comment: I have just discovered that the alluded problem still appears in the new (2018) version of the "Kourovka Notebook" (Collection of unsolved problems in group theory). Concretely:

11.38. Does there exist a finitely presented Noetherian group which is not almost polycyclic? (S. V. Ivanov)

See https://kourovka-notebook.org/

Comment: For noetherian (not f.p.) groups, solvable WP (i.e. solvable membership for the trivial subgroup) can be undecidable. I don't know whether solvable MP holds for noetherian groups with solvable WP.

Comment: It's certainly still an open problem.